# grub-install: error: install device isn't specified

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

So I had a windows 10 installed on one of my partitions and all my files on the other. I decided to get rid of windows and install **Ubuntu 16.04** . when attempted I chose something else and I chose to format the first partition to **ext4 and mounted it to /** and chose to **format** it. I also made a **960MB swap** partition. **I didn't connect my laptop to Internet** during the installation. my device is **Lenovo y50 with 256GB SSD hard drive**. Then I had so many problems after installation then and I did the process so many time I guess one of the times I used **BIOS** instead of **UEFI** and then every time I had the error *failed to install grub2 package to /target etc* so I found somewhere that I should make a **200MB fat32 partition with boot flag**. and I did and I finally could install my Ubuntu then whenever I wanted to install something I had a similar issue to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763472/what-can-i-do-to-fix-this-error-on-grub-efi/763746). So i ran this command:

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh
```

And then I started to have this new error:

> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you
>   want to continue? [Y/n] Y Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed
>   (1.66.14+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ... Installing for x86_64-efi
>   platform. grub-install: error: cannot open
>   `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/moddep.lst': No such file or directory. dpkg:
>   error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure): 
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   grub-efi-amd64-signed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
>   code (1)

So what should I do!? I'm really sick of this issue!
Is there anyway I could completely unistall grub2 and reinstall it again?
Is it safe and easy to use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?
Where can I find the moddep.lst file!?

**Update**

I ran:

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/i386-pc/* /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/
```

Now I get the following error:

> Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.14+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14) ...
>   Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: error: install device
>   isn't specified. dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed
>   (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
>   error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   grub-efi-amd64-signed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
>   code (1)
>   actually I wonder why I have the i386 directory anyway since my system is 64bit and I have installed amd64.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing grub (I am using pop-os 20.10 LTS) with this command line

```
sudo apt install grub-efi grub-common grub-customizer
```

Worked out for me for all the missing dependencies.

Comment: Please [visit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636502/grub-rescue-error). I have tried `sudo apt install grub-efi grub-common grub-customizer` then, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried sudo apt install grub-efi grub-common grub-customizer then, what to do? –
> user1166068
> Feb 26, 2021 at 9:30

I didn't see anyone pointing it out, so after running `sudo apt install grub-efi grub-common grub-customizer` should you get the **device not specified** error, simply add the device to the command like so

`sudo grub-install /dev/[yourDeviceName]`

Should be the same device you are running your system from, in my case `/dev/sda` for example.

To check mounted devices run `df -h`

Comment: *Should be the same device you are running your system from* Not necessarily. **It must be the same device where the ESP (EFI System Partitions) is** and that can be different from the one where the system is actually installed. It should be the same ONLY if you have a single drive.